# upowerd consuming 100% cpu

Tags: cpu, power-management, top

upowerd is consuming nearly 100% of CPU.

I am currently affected by this issue on both a Lenovo Thinkpad E520 and on a desktop PC running Core i7 and Asus Z170a motherboard. Both run Kubuntu 15.10. However, I have found reports of this problem on several different distros (from Fedora to Arch to Ubuntu) going back several years.

I found these bug reports, but I don't find any workaround or solution:

FS#40444 : [upower] upowerd 0.99.0-2 eats all resources
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40444

Bug #861642 “upowerd uses 100% cpu till killed” : Bugs : upower package : Ubuntu
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/861642

Bug #876279 “Upowerd excessive CPU usage” : Bugs : upower package : Ubuntu
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/876279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After discovering this page I did some experimentation; connecting and disconnecting my iPhone 4 (ios 7.1.2) with up-to-date Ubuntu 16.10 using Unity running on a MacBookPro7,1

I found that just confirming **Trust** on the *iPhone* **had no effect**; { in fact I am asked repetitively to allow trust on this system unless I indicate 'Don't Trust', but that is another matter }

I also found that *usbmuxd* is playing a big part in this problem, so forcing *usbmuxd* to exit is a quick and dirty fix.

```
/usr/sbin/usbmuxd -X
```

After NOT Trusting and running the command I **can charge the phone**, and connect to it as a wireless or bluetooth hotspot without the cpu time consumption. { the phone also stops asking whether to trust the computer or not, and *usbmuxd* stops restarting }

Answer (score 17):

Do you have an iphone connected to the computer? This happens to me whenever I connect my iphone to it.

`Linux arjun-thinkpad 4.4.7-1-lts #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 17:26:39 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Indeed, this is the case for me too - how do I fix it though, so that I can leave my iPhone connected ?

Comment: @JonasCz I did a little digging, but couldn't find a solution. It's not a huge deal for me, so I haven't bothered to pursue it. If you do figure it out, could you please post here?

Comment: Same thing here, can confirm.

Comment: According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/818965/upowerd-hogging-cpu it helps to select "Trust this computer" when connecting the iPhone to the computer. This solves the problem for me.

Comment: Here, I **unplug** my iPhone and save `10 %CPU`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  It seems to be an issue if I boot up with the iPhone already plugged in.  Instead,

unplug the iPhone and boot.  After everything is up and running, plug the iPhone back in and "trust" and enter pass code.  cpu usage should gradually drop.

just don't boot up with the iPhone plugged in and this should not be a problem.  At least that is how it was for me.